# Convert Json to Java object using reserved variables

Tags: java, json, reserved-words, reserved

Am having a JSON file as below

```
{
      "boost_id": "75149",
      "content_id": "627680",
      "headline": "19 Rare Historical Photos That Will Leave You Breathless ",
      "target_url": "http://stars.americancolumn.com/2016/02/21/historical-photos/?full=1",
      "return": "district" 
 }
```

I need  to convert json string to java object. Since the "return" is known as Java reserved keywords am unable to form a Dto with return variable.

Is there any other way to use the reserve variable and convert the above JSON to JAVA object.

Below is my Dto structure,

```
public class RevcontentReportResponse {

    private String boost_id;
    private String content_id;
    private String headline;
    private String target_url;
//  private String return;

    public String getBoost_id() {
        return boost_id;
    }

    public void setBoost_id(String boost_id) {
        this.boost_id = boost_id;
    }

    public String getContent_id() {
        return content_id;
    }

    public void setContent_id(String content_id) {
        this.content_id = content_id;
    }

    public String getHeadline() {
        return headline;
    }

    public void setHeadline(String headline) {
        this.headline = headline;
    }

    public String getTarget_url() {
        return target_url;
    }

    public void setTarget_url(String target_url) {
        this.target_url = target_url;
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

File json = new File("historic.json");
RevcontentReportResponse cricketer = mapper.readValue(json, RevcontentReportResponse.class);
System.out.println("Java object created from JSON String :");
System.out.println(cricketer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [JsonProperty](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki/Jackson-Annotations#property-naming) annotation:

```
@JsonProperty("return")
private String returnValue;
```

That said, JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation, and return is also a JavaScript keyword (and it's the same for many other languages). You'd better change the name of the attribute in the JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a field with its getter/setter and annotate it with `@JsonProperty("return")`.